# How to Run Messaging API Code to Listen to Telegram, Slack, and Email Bot on Loopback4 App Startup?

Tags: typescript, loopback4

I am building a messaging API that listens to my Telegram, Slack, and Email bot. I want to ensure that the code that listens to these bots starts automatically when my Loopback app starts. However, I am encountering issues with achieving this.

I have tried several methods, including adding the code to the boot script and using lifecycle events, but nothing seems to work. I believe there may be an issue with my code or my understanding of how the Loopback framework works.

I would appreciate any assistance on how to correctly configure my Loopback app to ensure that my messaging API code starts listening to my bots on startup. Additionally, any tips or best practices on how to integrate multiple messaging platforms into a single API would also be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.